# Pass variable to module before import

Tags: python, import, module

I have the following setup.  I am trying to load a module in a.py dynamically (from c.py in this case, and call it toBeLoaded).  Then I want to import another module fileB which has a class that will inherit the class toBeLoaded.anotherClass.  I know it would solve the problem if I imported c.py in b.py, but since I am loading c.py dynamically, I am not sure how to accomplish that.  It would work if I could somehow pass a variable to b.py before it is imported, but I am not sure how to do that.

Here is my current setup.

a.py

```
import imp
from optparse import OptionParser

parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-c","--configFile",dest="configFile", default="c.py",help="")
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()

modulePath=options.configFile
toBeLoaded = imp.load_source('toBeLoaded',modulePath)

import b
```

b.py

```
class TestClass(toBeLoaded.anotherClass):
  def __init__(self):
    print self.x
    #do stuff here
```

c.py

```
class anotherClass():
  def __init__(self):
    self.x=5
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 6, in <module>
    import b
  File "/test/b.py", line 1, in <module>
    class TestClass(toBeLoaded.anotherClass):
NameError: name 'toBeLoaded' is not defined
```

Comment: I dont quite understand why you not just import anotherClass in b.py and im pretty sure you can't pass anything to a module and you shouldn't tryit either.

Comment: I may have oversimplified.  But the way a.py works is I am dynamically loading a module using sys.argv.  I will edit above code.

Comment: Actually I am using from optparse import OptionParser

Answer (score 0):

As I said, im pretty sure you can't do so and even if you find a way you should not do it.

You should consider to organize your code in another way instead of crawling yourself through the import internals. :)

Edit: As your goal seems to load a config file I suggest to either:

1. use basic data types instead of external class references
2. take a look on [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html)
3. use [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

Comment: I can simply move TestClass to a.py to solve the problem.  But I was trying to keep files relatively simple.  Do you have any other recommendations for how to solve this?

Comment: In my opinion the only files which should be as simple as possible are configfiles (I mentioned 3 options above) and you're program in general won't be simpler at all if you bypass the normal import mechanisms a normal programmer would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the cleanest way to do it.  But the problem is fixed if c.py is changed to

c.py

```
from __main__ import modulePath
import imp
toBeLoaded = imp.load_source('toBeLoaded',modulePath)

class TestClass(toBeLoaded.anotherClass):
  def __init__(self):
    print self.x
    #do stuff here
```